# "apt-cache search" can't find "linux-header-5.8.0-2-amd64"

Tags: linux, debian, kernel-module

My OS is debian 11 with kernel 5.8.0-2-amd64.
I need "linux-headers-5.8.0-2-amd64" to make my own kernel module.
Then, I use "apt-cache search" and "apt search" to find it, but both of them can't find it.
Where can I download this header?

The following is the content of "/etc/apt/sources.list":

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free 
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free
```

Comment: What exactly is your command  for `apt-cache search`?

Comment: I use it like, apt-cache search "linux-header-*"

Comment: headers, not header

Comment: and it should be without quotes ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to download the header and install them.

http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2020/08/install-linux-kernel-5-8-ubuntu/

Here is a good tutorial how to compile a kernel and download the headers. In Newer version it's `linux-headers-amd64`. You can try this in your version to get the headers for your version.

I have checked the versions. So you should make a dist-upgrade to the kernel which is in your repo.

https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/linux-headers-amd64

For Debian 11 it's 5.9 then you can install the headers from the repo if that is possible.

Comment: Is ubuntu headers also working for debian?